# Wordpress theme is not showing same to the preview

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, custom-wordpress-pages

Today i installed Wordpress and install Shapely theme just to get started but result is not as i expected.
I installed many other themes but same result for all. 
Can we see result as we saw in the theme preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing a wordpress theme, you need to **activate** it. Go in your backend to **Design -> Themes** and click the blue button at the theme you want to use.

The preview of themes often work with sample data, to show you the functionalities of the theme. So the theme does not look the same, if you do not have the same content.

There can demo content be downloaded for most themes. I checked the name of your theme:

https://colorlib.com/wp/support/shapely/

under **2. Import Shapely demo content and widget content.** there is a link to download demo content and a description how to get it into your wordpress site.

For other themes, just search for the theme name and add "demo content", "dummy data" or something like this. It could be the case for some themes (often low priced), that do not offer a demo content. So you need to read through the documentation of the theme to build it like in the demo.

Hope this helps.